# I used to send email from php by cloud hosted server but sended mail lended in spam folder always

Tags: email, cloud

I used to transfer domain by changing A records .is Name server changing would be better way. I also getting problem in sending emails from as it goes to spam folder .

I have set dkim ,dmarc and spf but email reputation not gained

Comment: mail send if sanded by ISP like godaddy or bigrock  problem arise when i used self hosted server or cloud virtual server

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons why your email may be going to junk or the spam folder. The common reasons are:

- Your email content.
- Blacklisted domain.

To resolve this issue, I suggest sending emails using [PHP Mailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) to handle encryption, authentication, HTML messages, and attachment. If you are using this solution, please keep in mind you'll have to use your email carefully i.e., only sending emails to people who have shown genuine interest in your project, remove unsubscribers from your email list and avoid bulk sending as some email providers tend to flag this as spam.

If you don't want the headache of managing all this, I'll suggest using a mail delivery service like [Mailgun](https://alternativeto.net/software/mailgun/?license=free).

*Ad: Ever in the market to host an event to promote your business? Have a look at [Vivus Create](https://vivushub.com/vivus/?adFor=events&requireAction=yes&ref=stackoverflow), it's an excellent tool to help manage your events, social media and sponsors all in one place.*